# Simple ways to concatenate only two elements with pattern of array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, optimization

I have an array of strings, which are either an asterisk by itself (`"*"`) or something else.

I want to "merge" consecutive asterisks as follows:

> If there are one or more asterisks in a row, remove them from the array, and prepend a *single* asterisk to the next non-asterisk element. If the asterisks are at the end of the array, simply remove them.

Some smaller examples:

```js
[..., "*", "4", ...]      => [..., "*4", ...] // concat asterisk with string at the right
[..., "*", "*", "4", ...] => [..., "*4", ...] // remove first asterisk
[..., "*", "4", "*"]      => [..., "*4"]      // remove last asterisk
[..., "4", "*", "*", "*"] => [..., "4" ]      // remove all asterisk which have no alphanumeric at its right
```

For this full-sized input:

```js
let data = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "*", "*", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "*", "34", "*", "36", "37", "*", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "*", "54", "*", "56", "57", "58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", "69", "70", "71", "72", "73", "*", "*", "*", "*", "78", "79", "80", "81", "82", "83", "84", "85", "86", "87", "88", "89", "*", "91", "92", "93", "94", "95", "*", "97", "*", "*"];
```

The result should be:

```
["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "*9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "*34", "*36", "37", "*39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "*54", "*56", "57", "58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", "69", "70", "71", "72", "73", "*78", "79", "80", "81", "82", "83", "84", "85", "86", "87", "88", "89", "*91", "92", "93", "94", "95", "*97"]
```

How can I implement this? Here is my attempt:

```js
let data = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "*", "*", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "*", "34", "*", "36", "37", "*", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "*", "54", "*", "56", "57", "58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", "69", "70", "71", "72", "73", "*", "*", "*", "*", "78", "79", "80", "81", "82", "83", "84", "85", "86", "87", "88", "89", "*", "91", "92", "93", "94", "95", "*", "97", "*", "*"];
let output = data.map((d, index, arr) => arr[index - 1] === '*' ? '*'+d : d).filter(d => d !== '*');
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Hey, what should be the output for this case- `*, 34, *, 36`? Should it be, `*34, *36` or `*34, 36`?

Comment: The output is `*34, *36`

Comment: Microbenchmarking is tempermental at best. Take the time to test the various solutions yourself against meaningful datasets and using an up-to-date library. This is a simple process and so basic iteration is generally going to win out. A quick online test fo the top-voted answers is here: [benchmark](https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/24295/0/array-compaction#latest_results_block)

Comment: This is the subject of [a meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/423811/how-to-notify-all-answerers-about-change-of-my-question-on-so).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this in a single loop by simply checking if the current element is an `*`, if not then `push()`, concatenating if the previous element was an `*`.

```js
function collapse(array) {
  const result = [];

  for (const [i, n] of array.entries()) {
    if (n !== '*') {
      result.push(array[i - 1] === '*' ? `*${n}` : n);
    }
  }

  return result;
}

console.log(...collapse(['*', 1, 2, '*', 3]));
console.log(...collapse(['*', '*', 2, '*', 3]));
console.log(...collapse(['*', '*', 2, '*', '*']));
console.log(...collapse(["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "*", "*", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "*", "34", "*", "36", "37", "*", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "*", "54", "*", "56", "57", "58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", "69", "70", "71", "72", "73", "*", "*", "*", "*", "78", "79", "80", "81", "82", "83", "84", "85", "86", "87", "88", "89", "*", "91", "92", "93", "94", "95", "*", "97", "*", "*"]));
```

Or the same logic in a `reduce()` call if you prefer

```js
const input = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "*", "*", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "*", "34", "*", "36", "37", "*", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "*", "54", "*", "56", "57", "58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", "69", "70", "71", "72", "73", "*", "*", "*", "*", "78", "79", "80", "81", "82", "83", "84", "85", "86", "87", "88", "89", "*", "91", "92", "93", "94", "95", "*", "97", "*", "*"];

const result = input.reduce((a, n, i, { [i - 1]: prev }) => {
  if (n !== '*') {
    a.push(prev === '*' ? `*${n}` : n);
  }
  return a;
}, []);

console.log(...result);
```

---

Alternatively you can avoid the second condition (and thus the second array access) in the concatenation by storing the previous value on each iteration. This is similar to the state machine answer in function, but avoids the repeated destructuring and object creation.

```js
function collapse(array) {
  const result = [];

  let prev = '';
  for (const n of array) {
    if (n !== '*') {
      result.push(prev + n);
      prev = '';
    } else {
      prev = '*';
    }
  }

  return result;
}

console.log(...collapse(['*', 1, 2, '*', 3]));
console.log(...collapse(['*', '*', 2, '*', 3]));
console.log(...collapse(['*', '*', 2, '*', '*']));
console.log(...collapse(["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "*", "*", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "*", "34", "*", "36", "37", "*", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "*", "54", "*", "56", "57", "58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", "69", "70", "71", "72", "73", "*", "*", "*", "*", "78", "79", "80", "81", "82", "83", "84", "85", "86", "87", "88", "89", "*", "91", "92", "93", "94", "95", "*", "97", "*", "*"]));
```

---

Basic online [benchmark](https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/24296/0/array-compaction-v2#latest_results_block)

| Test case name | Result |
| --- | --- |
| Simple loop (store prev) | 1,228,712 ops/sec ±2.22% (64 runs sampled) |
| Simple loop | 351,955 ops/sec ±0.24% (67 runs sampled) |
| State machine | 31,174 ops/sec ±0.27% (64 runs sampled) |

Answer (score 4):

This can be modeled as a simple state machine:

[image: State Diagram]

We start with an empty state value.  When the state is empty and we encounter an asterisk, we move to the asterisk state.  When we encounter a different value, we append it to our output and stay in the empty state.  When we're in the asterisk state, if we encounter an asterisk, we stay in the asterisk state and leave the output alone.  When we encounter something else, we append `*<value>` to our output, and return to the empty state.  There's no cleanup needed at the end; we just return the output.

We can code that state machine with a simple `reduce` call, which tracks a `state` variable and the current `output` array, like this:

```js
const trimAsterisks = (data) => data .reduce (
  ({state, output}, val) => val == '*' 
    ? {state: '*', output} 
    : {state: '', output: output .concat (state + val)}, 
  {state: '', output: []}
) .output

const data = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "*", "*", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "*", "34", "*", "36", "37", "*", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "*", "54", "*", "56", "57", "58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", "69", "70", "71", "72", "73", "*", "*", "*", "*", "78", "79", "80", "81", "82", "83", "84", "85", "86", "87", "88", "89", "*", "91", "92", "93", "94", "95", "*", "97", "*", "*"]

console .log (trimAsterisks (data))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Because our state value is either an asterisk or an empty string, we can just prepend it to our value and append the result to the output array.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function myFunc(data) {
  let result = [];
  for (let index = 0; index < data.length - 1; index++) {
    let current = data[index];
    let next = data[index + 1];
    // if current and next create a pair like *<number>
    if (current == '*' && next != '*') {
      result.push(current + next)
    }
    // if current is not star and not pushed already
    if (current != '*' && !result.includes(`*${current}`)) {
      result.push(current);
    }
  }
  return result;
}


// Ex: 1
console.log(myFunc(["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "*", "*", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "*", "34", "*", "36", "37", "*", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "*", "54", "*", "56", "57", "58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", "69", "70", "71", "72", "73", "*", "*", "*", "*", "78", "79", "80", "81", "82", "83", "84", "85", "86", "87", "88", "89", "*", "91", "92", "93", "94", "95", "*", "97", "*", "*"]))
// Ex: 2
console.log(myFunc(["1", "*", "4", "5"]))
// Ex: 3
console.log(myFunc(["1", "*", "*", "4", "5"]))
// Ex: 4
console.log(myFunc(["1", "*", "4", "*"]))
// Ex: 5
console.log(myFunc(["1", "4", "*", "*", "*"]))
```

**Explanation-**

1. Loop over the elements.
2. Check the current item's and next item's order, if it's `*<non_star>` then merge both and push them into the new array.
3. If the current item is not a star and not present already as `*<curent_item>` then push it too.

Comment: What if length of data is 100 like my data?

Comment: I guess, it will work. I trimmed it to understand the better. Let me update the answer with 100 data.

Comment: Can you please check both examples if it is providing the correct output?

Comment: Yes, your code works. But please see my updated data

Comment: It's working with your updated data too. Please see the answer, I updated the data in my answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an optimized version of pilchard's "Simple loop (store prev)" solution:

```js
function collapsePrev2(array) {
  const result = [];

  let prev = false;
  for (const n of array) {
    if (n !== '*') {
      if (prev) {
         result.push('*' + n);
         prev = false;
      }
      else
        result.push(n);
    }
    else
      prev = true;
  }

  return result;
}
```

The differences are:

- Store a boolean in `prev` instead of a string
- Concatenate strings only when necessary (not at each iteration)
- Reset `prev` only when necessary

The [benchmark](https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/24332/0/array-compaction-v3#latest_results_block) gives:

| Test case name | Result |
| --- | --- |
| collapsePrev | 1,130,945 ops/sec ±0.59% (65 runs sampled) |
| collapsePrev2 | 1,299,316 ops/sec ±0.73% (67 runs sampled) |

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there! The one missing feature is testing for successive `*`s?

```js
const datasets = [
  ["1", "*", "4", "5"],
  ["1", "*", "*", "4", "5"],
  ["1", "*", "4", "*"],
  ["1", "4", "*", "*", "*"],
]

const output = datasets.map(
  dataset => dataset
  .map((d, index, arr) => arr[index - 1] === '*' && d !== '*' ? '*' + d : d)
  .filter(d => d !== '*')
)

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

As for the OP's use case I propose an array [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join), regex-based string [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and string [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) approach where the regular expressions patterns is as follows ...

```
/(?:,\*)+(?:,(?<value>[^,*]+))?/g
```

... and its [description is provided with the pattern's test/playground page](https://regex101.com/r/I3XdKM/1).

The advantage comes with the expressiveness of dealing with the provided array data as one big string (hence `join`ing the array) and processing it with a single regex-based `replace` task, where the intermediate replacement result is `split` again into the final array structure.

```js
const sampleData = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "*", "*", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "*", "34", "*", "36", "37", "*", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "*", "54", "*", "56", "57", "58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", "69", "70", "71", "72", "73", "*", "*", "*", "*", "78", "79", "80", "81", "82", "83", "84", "85", "86", "87", "88", "89", "*", "91", "92", "93", "94", "95", "*", "97", "*", "*"];

// see ... [https://regex101.com/r/I3XdKM/1]
const regXAsteriskSequences = /(?:,\*)+(?:,(?<value>[^,*]+))?/g;

console.log(
  'array `join` and regex-based `replace` only ...',
  sampleData
    .join(',')
    .replace(regXAsteriskSequences, (_, value = null) =>
      (value !== null) && `,*${ value }` || ''
    )
);
console.log(
  'array `join`, regex-based `replace` and string `split` ...',
  sampleData
    .join(',')
    .replace(regXAsteriskSequences, (_, value = null) =>
      (value !== null) && `,*${ value }` || ''
    )
    .split(',')
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

**Edit** ... in order to provide a ***"more to the ground"*** approach.

```js
const sampleData = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "*", "*", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "*", "34", "*", "36", "37", "*", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "*", "54", "*", "56", "57", "58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", "69", "70", "71", "72", "73", "*", "*", "*", "*", "78", "79", "80", "81", "82", "83", "84", "85", "86", "87", "88", "89", "*", "91", "92", "93", "94", "95", "*", "97", "*", "*"];

function trimAsteriskSequences(arr) {
  let result = [], idx = -1, currentItem, nextItem;

  while (currentItem = arr[++idx]) {
    if (currentItem !== '*') {

      result.push(currentItem)
    } else if (
      (currentItem === '*') &&
      (nextItem = arr[idx + 1]) &&
      (nextItem !== '*')
    ) {
      result.push(['*', nextItem].join(''))
      ++idx;
    }
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(
  trimAsteriskSequences(sampleData)
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

***Final Note*** I myself find the regex based variant still more elegant and expressive though the later provided above solution might be easier to read/maintain for beginners.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a solution.

```
let data = ["0", "7", "*", "9", "33", "34", "*", "*", "36","54", "*", "89", "*","97", "98", "*"];


let newArr = [];
let isAstrictFound = false;
data.map(val =>{
  if(val !== '*'){
    let newVal = isAstrictFound ? '*'+val.toString() : val.toString();
    newArr.push(newVal);
    isAstrictFound = false;
  }else{
    isAstrictFound = true;
  }
});
console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: You shouldn't really be using `map` since it's purpose is to return a _new_ array.

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75800627/edit), not here in comments (****** ****** ****** ****** ****** ****** ****** ****** ****** ****** ****** ***without*** ****** ****** ****** ****** ****** ****** ****** ****** ******   "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).